How to open link in new tab using selenium when html does not provide link?
I'm trying to write a selenium script that is capable of clicking on the "Apply" button on a LinkedIn job posting such that the job posting is opened in a new tab in chrome.
However, it looks like LinkedIn doesn't include the job posting link in it's html at all.
If that's the case, is my goal still achievable?

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=software%20engineer&location=United%20States')

job_block = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "scaffold-layout__list-container")
jobs = job_block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
n = len(jobs)
i = 0

while i < n:
    driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
    jobs = job_block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
    n = len(jobs)
    i += 1
    # f.write(str(len(jobs)) + '\n')
    if i < n:
        ActionChains(driver).double_click(jobs[i]).perform()
        driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        d1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-search__job-details--wrapper")
        d2 = d1.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "job-view-layout.jobs-details")
        d3 = d2.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "t-14")
        d4 = d3.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mt5")
        d5 = d4.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "display-flex")
        d6 = d5.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-s-apply.jobs-s-apply--fadein.inline-flex.mr2")
        driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
        try:
            #f.write("trying\n")
            #d7 = d6.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-apply-button--top-card")
            #d7.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button").click()
            button = d6.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-apply-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--icon-right.artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--primary.ember-view")
            button.click()
            f.write('button clicked\n')
        except:
            continue


Did you try clicking the USE tag?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. This includes HTML.

you can just create a new tab, switch the driver to the new tab, navigate to this same page, and then click the link.  In Selenium 4, new tab and switch to are all in one command: driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
